# Rough y(x) approximation for simplified Cubic Bezier curve

Tags: approximation, bezier-curve

I need to get a very rough (and fast) $y(x)$ approximation of a simplified Cubic Bezier curve to use in my animation code, where there's only one control variable:

$$
P_0 = (0, 0)\\
P_1 = (0, 0)\\
P_2 = (k, 1)\\
P_3 = (1, 1)\\
$$

The curve looks like this: http://cubic-bezier.com/#0,0,.25,1 (here $k = 0.25$)

With these control points, I get the following parametric Cubic Bezier equation (with $t = 0..1$):

$$
x(t) = 3k (1-t) t^2 + t^3\\
y(t) = 3 (1-t) t^2 + t^3
$$

Or, in other representation:

\begin{aligned}
x(t) = (1 - 3k) t^3 + 3k t^2\\
y(t) = -2 t^3 + 3 t^2
\end{aligned}

How do I get a very very rough and simple $y(x)$ approximation for the given $k$ (0..1 too)? Solving the system is too difficult, and binary search is not suitable here because it's too slow. I've been banging my head around this for quite some time... Any ideas?

**update**: the approximation needs to be done in such way so that the curve is convex, like on the example, and starting/ending angles are approximately the same. Tried 3-point and 4-point Lagrange interpolating polynomials with no luck (see comments)...

**update 2**: discovered [De Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm), but it still seems too complex and slow for my needs. I need a really rough approximation within the constraints, and visually it looks simple, but on practice...

Comment: "rough" - sample a few points, and form an interpolating polynomial from them.

Comment: J.M, good idea! What is the simplest and fastest way of, say, 3-point polynomial interpolation (t=0, t=0.5, t=1)?

Comment: If it's just three points, you should be able to easily write down the Lagrange interpolant. On the other hand, a cubic (which would require four points) would have more flexibility, since a cubic can display inflexion points, while a quadratic cannot.

Comment: OK, I tried a 3-point Lagrange interpolant but the problem is that it produces curves where $y$ goes above $1$, see sample for $k = 0.25$ here: http://wolfr.am/YQBwbK

Comment: Tried 4-point Lagrange interpolant ($t=0, 0.33, 0.66$) and it goes out of hand too... http://wolfr.am/STLA24

Comment: Of course, you should try shifting your interpolation points around; there's no reason to insist on, say, equispaced points...

Comment: That's true, but because the approximation needs to be programmatic (depending on k), that means there's no guarantee that any chosen set of points will produce a proper curve for the given k.

Comment: Well, you did say "rough"... anyway, you might want to look at Hermite interpolation; try matching derivatives as well as points to capture the shape of your curve better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach. Let
$$
\mathbf{x} = (x_1,\ x_2,\ x_3) = (0.1,\ 0.5,\ 0.9)
$$
and define the following polynomials:
\begin{align}
\theta_1(k) &= c_{11}k^4 + c_{12}k^3 + c_{13}k^2 + c_{14}k + 1,\\
\theta_2(k) &= c_{21}k^4 + c_{22}k^3 + c_{23}k^2 + c_{24}k + 1,\\
\theta_3(k) &= c_{31}k^4 + c_{32}k^3 + c_{33}k^2 + c_{34}k + 1,
\end{align}
where $c$ is the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   0.16321393821380 & -1.14859165394532 & 2.51140325233548 & -2.52602553660396\\
   0.26949508735386 & 0.09905839089292 & -0.89714007482260 & -0.47141340342418\\
  -2.08424569212321 & 1.94150558704136 & -0.87990952487339 & 0.02264962995523
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, given $k\in[0,1]$, fit a parabola to the points $(x_i, \theta_i(k)),\ i=1,2,3$. That is, let
$$
\Theta(x) = \frac{(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)}\theta_1(k) + 
\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}\theta_2(k) + 
\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}\theta_3(k).
$$
Then $y$ as a function of $x$ is approximated by
$$
y = \Theta(x) (-2x + 3x^{2/3}) + (1-\Theta(x)) x.
$$
Below is the fitted function when $k=0.25$ (blue = true y, red = approx.).
[image: Function approximation when k=0.25]

Comment: Looks awesome! I'll try that, thank you very much!

Comment: how did you get the values for the matrix of c, and how did you get the values for x1, x2, x3?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to optimise it firs?
$$
x(t)=3k(1−t)t2+t3\\
y(t)=3(1−t)t2+t3
$$
means you do:

$$
a = t^{2}\\
b = at\\
c = 3(1-k)a
$$

so

$$
x(t) = kc+b\\
y(t) = c+b
$$

you can go deeper :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what to do next with this :)

Comment: 1. Interpolate with some step between points.

Comment: 2. Precalculate. Oh. I see answer with matrix. This is it!

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
real F(real x)
{
real y0=3*exp(2/3*log(x))-2*x, y13=3*x-2*x*sqrt(x), y1=x;
if(k<1/3)
{
real w=3*k; w-=(5.5*x*(1-x)-1)*w*(1-w);
return w*y13+(1-w)*y0;
}
else
{
real w=(3*k-1)/2; w-=(2*x-1+3*w*x^12)*w*(1-w);
return w*y1+(1-w)*y13;
}
}
```

I admit that exponents and logarithms are a bit slow but, perhaps, the precision is reasonable.

Comment: Nice approximation! How did y13 come up?

Comment: k=1/3 is solvable explicitly :)

Comment: Wow, that's some serious magic to me! Could you explain a little how did you come up with this? Sorry for a dumb question, I'm not very strong in Math...

Comment: Sure, but let me know first if this works for you or it is too slow or imprecise :).

Comment: OK, I'll try it! Not as easy to check as I used Wolfram Alpha for plotting, and it seems it doesn't support functions with several steps like this.

Comment: ---as I used Wolfram Alpha for plotting,--- My advice would be to get some decent graphic program that's out there for free. I personally like Asymptote, but it is not the only game in town :).

Answer (score 1):

What about a *clamped cubic spline* with three knots and two slopes? The three knots are
\begin{align}
\left(x(0),y(0)\right)&=(0,0),\\
\left(x(0.5),y(0.5)\right)&=\left(\frac{3k+1}{8},\frac12\right)\\
\left(x(1),y(1)\right)&=(1,1).
\end{align}
And the slopes can be derived from
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=(1-3k)3t^2 + 6kt=3(1-k)t^2+6kt(1-t^2)\ge0,\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=-6t^2+6t.
\end{align}
So $x(t)$ is monotonic increasing function in $t$ and the two tangent directions are given by:
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=0} &= \frac1k,\\
\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=1} &= 0.
\end{align}
See [this](http://www.math.psu.edu/jjb/web/html/sl455SP12/ch3/CH03_5C.pdf), for instance, for how to construct a clamped cubic spline given the knots and tangent directions. If cubic splines are too complicated, you may try a quadratic spline, or even interpolate $y(x)$ using the single quadratic function that passes through $(x(0),y(0)),(x(0.5),y(0.5))$ and $(x(1),y(1))$. At any rate, note that your interpolant is **not** only a function in $x$, but also a function in $k$.

Comment: Yep, cubic spline seems too complicated for my needs... I tried to interpolate through several points using quadratic function (using Lagrange interpolating polynomial), but no luck - see the comments to my question above.

Comment: But you can use a cubic function, which is a special case of cubic spline and is much simpler to derive. I mean, try $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Since you have $y(0)=0,y(1)=1,y'(0)=0$ and $y'(1)=1/k$, the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ can be solved easily. It's just four linear equations with four unknowns. Conceptually you only need to invert a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Oops, I meant $y(0)=0,y(1)=1,y'(0)=1/k$ and $y'(1)=0$.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a really great idea! Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: OK, tried the cubic function. It produces quite a close result but unfortunately with a part of the curve above 1. Example for $k=0.25$: http://wolfr.am/SFW2a8

Answer (score 1):

OK, I came up with a very rough approximation using simple [Penner's equations](http://upshots.org/actionscript/jsas-understanding-easing):

$$
y(x) = 1 - (1 - x)^{1/max(k,0.2)}
$$

Not sure if it's the best way but it seems to be working OK.

Comment: This equation is really amazing. `1-(1-x)^1.75` is super close to sine

Comment: `1.75194` is even better